# handlebars template not loading js script

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a home.handlebars file with an embedded script tag, but the script is never pulled in.The path to the js file is correct. Not sure why

```
blah
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>D3 Bar Chart</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2> D3 Bar Chart</h2>
    <svg class="bar-chart"></svg>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="c:/Users/xxxxx/xxxxx/Documents/d3/public/static/js/index2.js">
```

Comment: Is this file being opened from a browser? How is it being served?

Comment: I'm using a node http server.

Comment: Then you shouldn't use your local path to pinpoint the js file, But rather serve it through node. This can be done with [express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) or, if you want to keep using plain node, with [node-serve](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/)

Comment: How do I add the path to the js file in the handlebars template then ? Here is my route: app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  app.use(express.static('public'))
    res.render('home');
});

Comment: First of all, the `app.use` line must be outside of the `app.get` clause. And then, you should be able to access it via `/static/js/index.js`